# QGIS Server - Rendering error : 'Invalid map settings'

Tags: qgis, qgis-server

I try to set up my first QGIS Server project on a remote host in an apache web server.

I managed to run samples data from the documentation.

Then I created locally a project with one layer in QGIS Desktop, saved as .qgs file, then uploaded this file and the layerwith the same relative path as on my computer on the host.

I get an internal server error, here is the apache log :

```
06:22:55 INFO Server[122451]: Request URL: http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?MAP=/var/www/html/qgis/qgisfile.qgs&LAYERS=BATIMENT&SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&VERSION=1.3.0&WIDTH=1200&HEIGHT=800&CRS=EPSG:5490
06:22:55 INFO Server[122451]: Environment:
06:22:55 INFO Server[122451]: ------------------------------------------------
06:22:55 INFO Server[122451]: SERVER_NAME: xxx.xx.xxx.xx
06:22:55 INFO Server[122451]: REQUEST_URI: /cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?MAP=/var/www/html/qgis/qgisfile.qgs&LAYERS=BATIMENT&SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&VERSION=1.3.0&WIDTH=1200&HEIGHT=800&CRS=EPSG:5490
06:22:55 INFO Server[122451]: SCRIPT_NAME: /cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi
06:22:55 INFO Server[122451]: REMOTE_ADDR: yyy.yy.yyy.yyy
06:22:55 INFO Server[122451]: SERVER_PORT: 80
06:22:55 INFO Server[122451]: QUERY_STRING: MAP=/var/www/html/qgis/qgisfile.qgs&LAYERS=BATIMENT&SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&VERSION=1.3.0&WIDTH=1200&HEIGHT=800&CRS=EPSG:5490
06:22:55 INFO Server[122451]: REQUEST_METHOD: GET
06:22:55 INFO Server[122451]: QGIS_PROJECT_FILE: /home/user/qgis/projects/world.qgs
06:22:55 INFO Server[122451]: SERVER_PROTOCOL: HTTP/1.1
Headers:
------------------------------------------------
"Accept" :  "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"
"Host" :  "xxx.xx.xxx.xx"
"User-Agent" :  "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
06:22:55 INFO Server[122451]: CRS:EPSG:5490
06:22:55 INFO Server[122451]: HEIGHT:800
06:22:55 INFO Server[122451]: LAYERS:BATIMENT
06:22:55 INFO Server[122451]: MAP:/var/www/html/qgis/qgisfile.qgs
06:22:55 INFO Server[122451]: REQUEST:GetMap
06:22:55 INFO Server[122451]: SERVICE:WMS
06:22:55 INFO Server[122451]: VERSION:1.3.0
06:22:55 INFO Server[122451]: WIDTH:1200
06:22:55 INFO Server[122451]: WMS Request parameters:
06:22:55 INFO Server[122451]:  - CRS : EPSG:5490
06:22:55 INFO Server[122451]:  - WIDTH : 1200
06:22:55 INFO Server[122451]:  - HEIGHT : 800
06:22:55 INFO Server[122451]:  - LAYERS : BATIMENT
06:22:55 INFO Server[122451]:  - VERSION : 1.3.0
06:22:55 INFO server[122451]: Parallel rendering deactivated
QPaintDevice: Cannot destroy paint device that is being painted
06:22:55 CRITICAL Server[122451]: Rendering error : 'Invalid map settings'
06:22:55 WARNING [122451]: finish() called twice
06:22:55 INFO Server[122451]: Request finished in 11 ms
```

1 - Can I get a more precise info on which settings is invalid ?

<strike>2 - The param "QGIS_PROJECT_FILE" is not ok, and I can't find where to set or unset it. I checked the environment variables and the QGIS Desktop settings for my projetc, but didn't find anything. Can't find mention of it in the QGS either</strike>
Edit : This param was set in the apache conf file

Answer (score 0):

So after countless hours of fiddling, I found that adding &BBOX=-90,-180,90,180 in the param's url seems to do the trick